# good bug tracking system for apt-get debian?

Tags: debian

got a new lenny installation now, we are a small team of 3 devs working on a already old and getting bigger project. We deploy the program every now and then to new client (like once a month), with new features. So we need to get a little more organized, i had installed trac some time ago on my debian etch server, however it installed the 0.10.3, and a bunch of things never worked right. Now these days we realized we really need the system. So i tried to upgrade and well, everything went to hell cause i messed up here and there.

thing is, i got a new lenny debian, but i wanted to ask you guys, if you recommend a different tracking system, or do you think trac would do the trick ? only requisite is that it´s easy to install and uninstall with apt-get. i really liked that you could browse the svn, however, the console admin did not like that much.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to love trac, but [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is a big improvement.  You can also look into distributed trackers like [Bugs Everywhere](http://bugseverywhere.org/) and not need a server.

**EDIT**

My preference has shifted to hosted solutions.  You can find companies that provide dedicated Redmine hosting or have one click installers for a VPS.  It pains me to say it but I would likely go with a proprietary service like GitHub, BitBucket, Assembla, FogBugz, ...